# Accessing constructor in C++

Tags: c++, oop, class, constructor

I'm trying to create a Node object using class Node:

```
int main(){
    for(int i=0; i< 20; i++)
        Node *handle = new Node(i, 10);
}

class Node{
 public:
    static vector<Node> map;
    static int totalNodes;
    vector<Node> connections;   
    int NodeID;

    Node(int ID, int weight){
    NodeID = ID;
    CreateConnections(weight);
    totalNodes++;
    map.push_back(*this);
}
```

For some reason I get

```
'Node' : undeclared identifier
'Node' handle : undeclared identifier
 syntax error : identifier node
```

Moving main() down after the class gives me

```
unresolved external symbol 
for Node::map and Node::totalNodes
```

I'm somewhat new to C++ so any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to end your class definition with ;

```
 class Node
 {
    //....
    map.push_back(*this);
 };  //^^^Cannot miss ;
```

Meanwhile, you need to put declaration of `Node` before `main`.

Another point:

```
 Node(int ID, int weight){
     NodeID = ID;
     CreateConnections(weight);
     totalNodes++;
     map.push_back(*this);
 }//missing closing } on constructor definition
```

The reason that you have undefined reference to `map` and `totalNodes` is because:
static members of class must be initialized outside class. so when you inline constructor tries to access them, they are not defined. so you have undefined reference.

You should do something like the following:

```
 class Node{
 public:
    static vector<Node> map;
    static int totalNodes;
    vector<Node> connections;   
    int NodeID;
    Node(int ID);
 };


int Node::totalNodes = 0;  //definition of static variables
vector<Node> Node::map;

//^^^define constructor outside class body
Node::Node(int ID){ //your second parameter for ctor not used, so remove it
    NodeID = ID;
    totalNodes++;
    map.push_back(*this);
}
```

Comment: I think you meant declaration instead of definition.

Comment: Okay, I added `class Node;` before main and added the semicolon at the end of the constructor, now it is giving me the unresolved external error that I listed in my question.

Sorry about the closing brace, I didn't paste the member functions and forgot the };

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring `Node` after its use. Just move the declaration before the `main` and you should be good:

```
class Node { ... };
int main() { ... }
```

You can also do a [*forward-declaration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) (declaration for the identifier without the definition) of the class:

```
class Node;
int main() { ... }
class Node { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put Node declaration prior to main where it is being used.
Just putting forward declaration is not enough as new Node in main requires Node to be declared.
As for the unresolved external, you need to define Node::totalNodes

```
int Node::totalNodes = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You either Need to do a Forward-declaration of `Node` like

```
class Node;

int main(){
   for(int i=0; i< 20; i++)
   Node *handle = new Node(i, 10);
}

class Node { }; //impelementation
```

or put `main` after defining `class Node`.

Comment: This won't work as to create new Node with new you need constructor to be declared.

Comment: Nonsense! It is a forward declaration, it is just that the class name is known. The compiler will do the rest.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2wbHmQ$0   source.cpp:8:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Node'

Comment: Are you kidding me? Did you read the comment? I am not pasting the whole code for the sake of readability.

Comment: Yes I did read. And I still can't see how forward declaration can help if constructor was involved. Even if you copy whole implementation, it won't help.

Comment: I didn't say it was best practice, just somethig to consider!

Comment: It not a bad vs good practice, it is question of correct vs incorrect.

Comment: At least top answer doesn't suggest such thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration

Answer (score 1):

Just bung the following line for the first line:

```
class Node;
```